# How to remove AlertDialog programmatically

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In an android application, I'm showing to the user an AlertDialog with no buttons, just a message. How can I destroy the AlertDialog programmatically so that it's not visible anymore? I tried with cancel() and dismiss() but they are not working, the view remains there.

```
AlertDialog.Builder test = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
test.setTitle("title");
test.setCancelable(true);
test.setMessage("message...");
test.create().show();
```

then I tried

`test.show().cancel()` and

```
test.show().dismiss()
```

but not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14445953/5188051 check this out

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should refer to the AlertDialog itself, not the builder.

```
AlertDialog.Builder test = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
test.setTitle("title");
test.setCancelable(true);
test.setMessage("message...");
ALertDialog testDialog = test.create();
testDialog.show();  // to show
testDialog.dismiss();  // to dismiss
```

Comment: I like you answer. it works as expected! :) thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
AlertDialog.Builder test = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
...

AlertDialog dialog = test.create().show();
```

Later you want to hide it:

```
 dialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

add this `alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);` to dismiss dialog if user touch outside

OR by click Device back button

```
alertDialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
})
```