# Android kotlin custom alert dialog won't programatically dismiss

Tags: android, kotlin

So I have an Alert Dialog with custom view.
I set it up in a different class form my fragment.

I have the same problem with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500087/how-to-remove-alertdialog-programmatically). The `.show()` is executed successfully but the `.dismiss()` wont't work, so the Dialog is still there even when `dismiss()` is called.

This is the class where i set up my Alert Dialog

```
class LoadingDialog(val currentContext: Context) {

   val loadingDialogLayout = LayoutInflater.from(currentContext).inflate(R.layout.loading_dialog_layout, null)

    val loadingDialog = AlertDialog
            .Builder(currentContext)
            .setView(loadingDialogLayout)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .create()


    fun show() {
        loadingDialog.show()
    }


    fun dismiss() {
        loadingDialog.dismiss()
    }
}
```

And this is how I call it in my fragment

```
....

LoadingDialog(activity as AppCompatActivity).show() <- Here

    EHealthServiceClient.eHealthInstance.requestPickup(orderId).enqueue(object : Callback<DefaultResponse> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<DefaultResponse>, t: Throwable) {

            LoadingDialog(activity as AppCompatActivity).dismiss() <- Here

            ...
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<DefaultResponse>, response: Response<DefaultResponse>) {

            LoadingDialog(activity as AppCompatActivity).dismiss() <- Here

            if (response.code() == 200) {
                ...
            } else {
               ...
            }

        }
    })
}
```

Did I miss something ? If there's anything I forgot to mention, feel free to ask. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are instantiating a new `LoadingDialog` class every time, and with that, you are creating a new `AlertDialog` instance.

Change your LoadingDialog class to an object like this

```
object LoadingDialog {

    lateinit var loadingDialog: AlertDialog

    fun show(activity: Activity) {
        val loadingDialogLayout = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.loading_dialog_layout, null)
        this.loadingDialog = AlertDialog
            .Builder(activity)
            .setView(loadingDialogLayout)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .create()

        loadingDialog.show()
    }


    fun dismiss() {
        if (::loadingDialog.isInitialized) {
            loadingDialog.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can simply call

```
LoadingDialog.show(<your-context>)
```

and

```
LoadingDialog.dismiss()
```